# Are all models of this theory isomorphic to $V_\omega$?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

Working in $\mathcal L(=,\in)_{\omega_1, \omega}$, add the following axioms:

$\textbf{Existence: } \exists x: x=x\\\textbf{Extensionality: } \forall z ( z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y) \to x=y  \\   \textbf{Finite Construction: } \\\bigwedge_{n \in \omega} \forall v_0..\forall v_n \exists x: x=\{v_0,..,v_n\} \\  \textbf{Finiteness: }\\ \forall x: x=\varnothing \lor \bigvee_{n \in \omega} \exists v_0 .. \exists v_n: x=\{v_0,..,v_n\}   \\ \textbf{Foundation: } \\ \forall x: \neg [ \bigwedge_{n \in \omega}   (\exists v_0..\exists v_n: \bigwedge_{i \in n} (v_{i+1} \in v_i) \land v_0 \in x)] $

I want to make sure that this theory has all of its models isomorphic to $V_\omega$. That is, it is categorical and thus complete in $\mathcal L(=,\in)_{\omega,\omega}$

Comment: Categoricity implies completeness in FOL. This is not FOL.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I've added this to the posting to clarify matters. Thanks

Comment: I'm confused by your edit. The theory is not a first-order theory. In what sense is it complete as a first-order theory?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, FOL is nothing but $\mathcal L_{\omega, \omega}$ right, so it is a fragment of this theory, so you can have partial completeness result, that is, it decides on every finitary sentence. The crucial matter is whether this theory is categorical, that is, if it speaks of ONE model up to isomorphism. If that is the case then it'll decide on all finitary sentences, since it has all FOL machinery in it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, take Noah's answer here, https://mathoverflow.net/a/448475/95347, and see the completeness he is referring to.

Comment: @Andreas Leitz, you changed the language over which this theory is complete. I think there are infinitary formulas in $\mathcal L_{\omega_1, \omega}$ that are undecidable in this theory, like those having infinitely many variable symbols and we cannot quantify over? Not sure though if this is relevant?

Comment: I changed it back again, but I think $\mathcal L(=,\in)_{\omega_1, \omega}$ is more natural and believed this is what you meant. In any case, there is only one model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes $V_\omega$ is, up to isomorphism, the only model of the theory you describe: If $\mathcal M$ is such a model then by induction on $n<\omega$ one can show that $\mathcal M$ has a member which is (isomorphic to) $V_n$, so there is a (unique) $\in^{\mathcal M}$-transitive substructure $\mathcal N$ of $\mathcal M$ which is isomorphic to $V_\omega$.  If $\mathcal M$ would contain a member $x_0$ not in $\mathcal N$, then there is $x_1\in^{\mathcal M} x_0$ which is not in $\mathcal N$ either as otherwise $x_0$ would be a finite subset of $\mathcal N$, so an element of $\mathcal N$. But going on like this one can construct a descending sequence $x_0\ni^{\mathcal M} x_1\ni^{\mathcal M} x_2\ni^{\mathcal M}\dots$, contradiction foundation. So $\mathcal M=\mathcal N\cong V_\omega$.